# 2 for me unknown differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have no idea how to solve this 2 differential equations.
Which types are they?

$$y' = \dfrac yx + \dfrac{2x^3\cos(x^2)}{y}\tag{1}$$
$$xy' = y^2 + y\tag{2}$$

Thank you

Comment: The second is separable. Can't read the first one.

Comment: The first is a [Bernoulli equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliDifferentialEquation.html).

Answer (score 5):

Number 2 is seperable:  divide by $x(y^2+y)$

For 1, multply by $y$ and define $z=y^2$ is a start.